# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver despite the fact it is in dependencies of gradle.build file

Tags: java, sql-server, gradle, intellij-idea, jdbc

I have read top 10-15 questions with answers by the following query https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver%22
However, I still don't understand why it doesn't work.
***Usual steps to solve this issue:***

1. Make sure that the jar is add to as a dependecy in your build/dependency management tool (Ant/Maven (pom.xml)/Gradle(gralde.build))
   Yes, it is in my case:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.4.0.jre8'
       testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.4.0.jre8'
   }
   ```

   in ***build.gradle*** file
   and ***gradle build*** command works without exceptions.
2. An alternative solution is to download jar file manually from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
   and then add it to a classpath. This solution is undesirable i don't want to do something manually that has to be done by a build tool.

So the question is why I am getting the error ***"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"*** and I cannot see this jar in the dependencies tab
[image]

despite the fact that the jar is mentioned in my ***build.gradle*** file in the dependency section as a compile-time dependency and as a Test time dependency : 
[image]

FYI:
That is how it is called in my code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: Have you tried to reimport your gradle file (click the reimport button in the gradle tab of IDEA). BTW: You don't need to declare `testCompile` if you also declare a dependency as `compile`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel plz post your comment as an answer I will accept it, you are right reimport helped me.Thank you for the prompt help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IntelliJ hasn't imported the addition of these dependency. This usually means that the auto-import is disabled.

You can reimport your gradle file by clicking the reimport button in the gradle tab of IDEA. You can enable auto-import by clicking the Gradle Settings button in the gradle tab, and enabling "Automatically import this project on changes in build script files".

On a separate not, you don't need to declare `testCompile` if you also declare a dependency as `compile`.